# How To Use WSDL Url

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, wsdl, glassfish

I wrote a java web service on Netbeans 6.9.1 and deployed on GlassFish 3.0.1
I have a wsdl url like this "http://localhost:8080/web2/service2Service?wsdl".
How can I use this url to access this web service from another java application.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to generate some Java that represents the client's view of the Web Service and then invoke that Java. Here's an article which explains some of the detail.

[Generating client from WSDL in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf)

The general idea is that you generate some Java classes from the WSDL. Those classes act as a proxy for the service you want to call. Your java invokes methods on the proxy objects, the generated code creates the appropriate SOAP messages, sends the HTTP request, interprets the response and your code just sees a Java result.

I just use the tooling built into Eclipse, but you will also find other suitable generators, for example in Apache's [Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html)

Comment: the site you sent was helpful. i also used this site
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html

Comment: The link is dead (or doesn't lead to where it should). This is why we emphasize on summarizing the content and not just dropping links. Please fix it or add a full answer and I'll remove my downvote :)

Comment: Yes. However I don't see value in replicating complex instructions, so I am providing links.

Answer (score 1):

1º U must save the content in a "myWebServices.wsdl" file

2º Run your Wsdl converter, all compilers have one of this, normally the name is WDSL.EXE
This process will create a new file with NameSpace or Package with the definitions of webservices built in.

3º Then imports this package or built a library.

Answer (score 0):

Develop web service Client in second application.
You can use Netbeans to create web service client by giving your wsdl url

Answer (score 0):

The document at this url is the actual *wsdl* (a description of the actual webservice, written in *WebService Definfition Language*).

The description includes information about the services url, the protocol(s), the method names and and data objects. Your application will use that information to call the remote methods of that service.

The protocol may or may not be SOAP, and without knowing the webservice details, it's quite impossible to recommend a toolset or methodology to use the webservice, there is no general approach. In most cases we see SOAP, for those services I recomment **soapUI** as a general tool to *use* and test SOAP based webservices and **apache axis** to implement java based service consumers.